# Will moving to EAR application make more sense

Tags: spring-mvc, java-8, tomcat8, hibernate-4.x

I have 3 different dependent web modules using same database. I also have one web module serving as common login for all the above 3 web apps and it has a different DB. Should I move to EAR application? Will this reduce the development/deployment time?

NOTE: All the web modules are developed using spring framework.